# Aggregate function isn't showing results with a count greater than 1

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm running this aggregate function, which is supposed to only show results when they have a count greater than 1. When I remove `'count': { '$gt': 1 }` the aggregate works, however it obviously shows all results. How should I use this count correctly?

```
db.getCollection('songs').aggregate([
{
  '$match': { 'is_song': 1, 'is_soundtrack': 0, 'count': { '$gt': 1 } }
},
{
  '$group': { '_id': { 'name': '$name', 'artist_id': '$artist_id' }, 'count': { '$sum': 1 } }        
},
{ 
   '$sort': { 'count': -1 }
}
])
```

Sample data:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5f93a43b4e8883298849ad18"),
  "name" : "Come Fly With Me",
  "song_id" : 5,
  "artist_id" : 5,
  "is_song" : 1,
  "is_soundtrack" : 0,
  "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-10-04T13:34:53.328Z")
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample data?

Comment: Sure thing, added above

Comment: Since the provided data doesn't have count field, I believe you are doing count through `$group`, and filter based on `count` > 1. You need another `$match` stage after `$group` to filter data.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add `'count': { '$gt': 1 }` in the first `$match` stage.

As the `count` field is only populated after the `$group` stage.

So, you need add another `$match` stage after `$group` stage for filtering document with the count value is greater than 1.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "is_song": 1,
      "is_soundtrack": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "name": "$name",
        "artist_id": "$artist_id"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "count": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hyjqByXFW-u)